# How to get the `data` from other `ng-repeat` element to current element directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a `dropdown` with my angular app. when a element is clicked, I am showing an `ul` with `li` of contents. (it's made by `ng-repeat`)

But using the `dropdown` `directive` is that possible to get the `scope` object from there. I am some what confused to handle this scenario any one help me please?

here is my html:

```
<div class="dropDownHeader">

                <h3 class="mainProjselected">
                    <span class="projectName"> 
                        <a ng-href="/" class="homeBtn"></a>
                        {{project.Name}}
                    </span>
                    <span class="dropDown dirDropDown"></span><!-- directive when this button is clicked i am shonwing mainProjects list -->
                </h3>
                <ul class="mainProjects">
                    <li ng-repeat='project in project.Projects' data="project" > {{project.Name}} </li> //i required the project data to dropdown.
                </ul>

            </div>
```

Here is my directive:

```
var dirDropDown = function () {

    return {

        restrict : 'C',

        scope : {

            data:'=' //how can i get data from `li`

        },

        link : function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

           //here the element is dropdown.

            var dropDownUL = element.parent().siblings('ul');

            element.on('click', function () {

                dropDownUL.show();
                scope.$apply();

            });

            dropDownUL.on('click', 'li', function ( target ) {

                //i can able to click on `li` - but how to get the `project' as data here?

            })



        }

    }

}

angular.module("tcpApp")
    .directive("dirDropDown", dirDropDown);
```

I don't know how to handle this. in case if i write separate `directive` to `li` list, I know that, that will works. But is there a alternative here? ( let me do both requirement with one directive, which belongs to drop down`

**or what is the correct way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't even need a directive for this to create a simple toggle button.

You can do this with `ng-click` and `ng-show`:

```
<span class="dropDown" ng-click="toggleList = !toggleList"></span>
<ul class="mainProjects" ng-show="toggleList">
```

Then you can also add same thing for the list items

```
<li ng-repeat='project in project.Projects' data="project"
    ng-click="scopeFunction(project);toggleList = !toggleList"  >
```

Answer (score 0):

All the variables declared in the `scope` property will be available inside your scope, thus `scope.data` should give you the project you want.

As a best practice though, prefer binding properties to the crontroller instead, by setting `bindToController: true` on the directive definition.

All this information is available in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).